# Помогите с cURL запросом к vk.com

Tags: php, http, вконтакте, curl

Всем привет, прошу помощи с cURL запросом к странице vk.com

Сегодня приобрел хостинг и загрузил на него наработки, чтобы протестировать в более масштабном режиме, но столкнулся с проблемой, что видимо ВК блокирует запросы с моего хостинга. У меня на локальном сервере работало все как часы, а на хостинге он  бесконечно пытался связаться с vk.com до таймаута и в итоге по истечению времени выдавал таймаут. Эта проблема была решена при помощи прокси, однако появилась другая: теперь ВК возвращал HTTP ошибку 400 Bad request.

С ней пытаюсь бороться уже около 6 часов и все никак, перебрал все настройки для cURL, попробовал различные заголовки и прочее, но ни в какую он не хочет хоть что-то делать.

Если что, то хостинг я сейчас использую 0hosting.me

Версия cURL на локальном сервере: 7.51.0

Версия cURL на 0hosting.me: 7.19.7

Буду благодарен каждому, кто попробует помочь и получить что-нибудь от vk.com

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста релевантные логи и код, который выполняет вызов.

Answer (score 0):

VK API **без разницы** кто, и с какого хостинга к нему обращается - на то это и API.

`400 Bad Request` - говорит вам о том что вы **неправильно** обратились к конечному сервису(VK API). Проверьте тело своего запроса и сравните его с документацией VK API, в которой указаны все примеры.

Comment: Каким методом отправляете запрос? И приложите к вопросу тело запроса, для большей ясности, чтобы я мог дать вам более точный и развернутый ответ. Пока основываясь на вашем вопросе, могу написать только это :)

Comment: Видимо мне не подходит VK API, раз я использую cURL. С запросом тоже всё в порядке, потому что на локалке все работает, как должно. Проблема с тем, что ВК блокирует такие запросы на хостингах, поэтому нужно использовать прокси.

Как сказали в англоязычных источниках, то проблема может быть с прокси, из-за мне возвращается ошибка 400 :/

Comment: Вы уверены что Вк блокирует подобные хостинги? Чем ваша локалка отличается?

Comment: Тем, что ВК нету смысла блокировать мой IP адрес, так как я не хостинг. Сейчас перебрал несколько прокси и 2 раза смог послать успешные запросы, но они идут слишком долго все равно.

Comment: Если бы вк блокировал хостинги, то вам ответ бы приходил не `400 Bad Request`, что означает "вы неправильно отправляете запрос"; А приходило бы: `403 Forbidden` или `405 Method not allowed`, либо коды 406, 409

Comment: Вк нет смысла блокировать хостинги, тогда бы все пришлось хостить на своих локальных машинах. Ваша проблема описана в ответе: `Bad Request`,  у вас что-то не так с синтаксисом запроса, и сервис попросту не может его "прочитать". Приложите код с локального и хостинга, отвечающий за отправку запроса.

Comment: Ну как показала практика, англоязычный источник был прав и проблема была с прокси. Проблема частично решена и ответ приходит, но страница почему-то все равно грузится до таймаута.

Comment: На прокси возможно была выставлена не та кодировка. И почему вы пользуетесь прокси - он и может быть источником таймаута.

Comment: Опять все сначала. Потому что иначе ВК блокирует запросы от IP хостинга.

Comment: Какая разница откуда вы шлете запрос, он видит это так: что ваш IP 86.173.45.89, что IP хостинга 90.34.34.89, смысл ему блокировать хостинги, для чего тогда вообще разрабатывался VK API чтобы всех хостинги блокировать, вам четко и ясно приходит ответ, что ВЫ неправильно посылаете запрос, у вас же написано `400 Bad Request`, при чем тут хостинг и ваша локалка и вообще при чем тут IP, прочитайте что такое API  и его смысл и вы найдете что его смыл НЕ ЗНАТЬ КТО отправляет на него запрос, ему по-барабану, хоть вы с телевизора отправьте, хоть с луны, он вам ответит.

Comment: Вы дорогу пытаетесь перейти по светофору вам горит зеленый, а вы идете и врезаетесь в забор и потом говорите "Светофор не дает передти дорогу". А потом начинает искать всякие обходные пути, чтобы перебежать эту дорогу и жалуетесь что у вас время вышло. Дк может это вы что-то неправильно делаете, а не люди которые разрабатывали этот сервис всей командой на протяжении достаточного времени, чтобы он был гибкий и везде работал, и даже вам ошибки показывает `400 Bad request`.

Comment: Проблему уже решил сам, увы, светофора у меня никакого не была и в моем случае необходим был только обход и он получился удачно.